# Make source stick (ignore \pause command)

Tags: beamer, pause

I'm making a presentation in LaTeX using the `beamer` document class, and have the following question:

I'm using `\pause` in my slides. However, in some slides, I have a source at the bottom of the page. How can I make this source appear in every "version" of the slide (i.e., not just after the final `\pause` has passed)?

Edit: Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Recall: Kronecker Product}
Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $B$ be some other matrix.
$$
A\otimes B := 
\begin{bmatrix}
    A_{1,1}\cdot B & \cdots & A_{1,n}\cdot B \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    A_{m,1}\cdot B & \cdots & A_{m,n}\cdot B
\end{bmatrix}
$$
\pause Important properties:
\begin{itemize}
    \item $ (A\otimes B)^{-1} = A^{-1}\otimes B^{-1}$.\pause
    \item $ (A\otimes B)(C\otimes D) = (AC\otimes BD)$ \small (if well-defined)
\end{itemize}

\tiny 
\vspace{\stretch{100}}  J. Martens and R. Grosse. Optimizing neural networks with kronecker-factored approximate curvature. ICML, 2015.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want the source at the bottom to be visible on every slide, not just after on the third.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: You can use commands like `\onslide` etc. (the overlay commands are documented in the beamer user guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually adding the source, you could add it as unnumbered footnote - this way it will automatically be displayed from the first slide in the frame:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\newcommand\source[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
      \parindent 1em\noindent%
      \raggedright
      \insertfootnotetext\par%
    }

    \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
    \footnotetext{#1}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Recall: Kronecker Product}
Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $B$ be some other matrix.
\[
A\otimes B := 
\begin{bmatrix}
    A_{1,1}\cdot B & \cdots & A_{1,n}\cdot B \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    A_{m,1}\cdot B & \cdots & A_{m,n}\cdot B
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\pause Important properties:
\begin{itemize}
    \item $ (A\otimes B)^{-1} = A^{-1}\otimes B^{-1}$.\pause
    \item $ (A\otimes B)(C\otimes D) = (AC\otimes BD)$ \small (if well-defined)
\end{itemize}

\source{J. Martens and R. Grosse. Optimizing neural networks with kronecker-factored approximate curvature. ICML, 2015.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Off-topic: you should not use `$$...$$`, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: ahh this is exactly what I wanted, TYVM!

Comment: @Protawn You're welcome!

Comment: What should I use instead of $$..$$? (or rather, what is ``better'' about \[ \])

Comment: @Protawn I just added a link that explains it